# Python - In a string find a character and print remaining part of string in a new line

Tags: python, replace, newline

I have a file which goes like this

```
abc  
abc+bcd+cdf  
adf;asfg
```

Find '+' or ';' and print remaining part of string in a new line !

output

```
abc  
abc  
bcd  
cdf  
adf  
asfg
```

Only Python !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

Demo:

```
>>> strs = "abc+bcd+cdf"
>>> re.sub(r'\+|;','\n',strs)
'abc\nbcd\ncdf'
```

Code:

```
>>> import re
>>> with open('abc') as f:
...     for line in f:       
...         line = re.sub(r'\+|;','\n',line.strip())
...         print line                              
...                                                 
abc
abc
bcd
cdf
adf
asfg
```

Comment: Great minds think alike ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)

```
import re

with open("myfile","rt") as f:
    for line if f:
        print re.sub("[;+]", "\n", line.strip())
```